# correct way to line break in json

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I am not able to do a line break on `\r\n` with the following payload on this screen.

I am trying to find out the correct json playload, I should send to the frontend so that it's interpreted as line break.

[image]

```
   {"allEvents": [{"data": [{"PSCPowerCableFailure": {"error_name": "patient_cart_running_on_battrey", "steps": {"1": {"step_body": {"step_link": {"type": "image", "url": "../../assets/patient-cart-running-on-battery_step_1.png"}}, "step_body_header": "Reconnect power cable to power outlet.", "step_body_text": "Confirm error is cleared on Vision Cart touchscreen. \r\nSwipe to the next troubleshooting screen if message does not clear.", "step_title": "Patient Cart Running on Battery"}, "2": {"step_body": {"step_link": {"type": "image", "url": "../../assets/patient-cart-running-on-battery_step_2.png"}}, "step_body_header": "Check circuit breaker on back of Patient Cart. Ensure that it is set to the ON (I) position.", "step_body_text": "Swipe to the next troubleshooting step if message does not clear.", "step_title": "Patient Cart Running on Battery"}, "3": {"step_body": {"step_link": {"type": "image", "url": "../../assets/exclamation-blue-circle-icon.png"}}, "step_body_header": "Call dVSTAT at 1.800.XXX.XXXX for additional assistance if required. \r\n  A representative can guide you through additional troubleshooting procedures.", "step_body_text": "System Information:\r\n  System Name: XXXXXX\r\n  Software Version: P8d", "step_title": "Patient Cart Running on Battery"}}}, "arm_number": null, "error_display_name": "Patient Cart Running on Battrey", "error_id": "PSCPowerCableFailure", "error_name": "patient_cart_running_on_battrey", "priority": 0, "show_default": "false"}], "error_content_id": "PSCPowerCableFailure", "type": "error_occurred"}]}
```

Comment: `<br>` is an HTML line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using angular, you most likely download your json and bind the resulting values to some template.

There are two ways to achieve line breaks then. You can either set linebreaks via HTML `<br>` tag and bind the attribute to an innerHTML of an element like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="retreivedJson.attributeContainingHTML"></div>
```

In this case you might need to use `Sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` on that attribute beforehand. An easy way to do that is to use a pipe like explained [here](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b).

Or you can send normal linebreaks with `\n`, in which case the element you are rendering it in needs to be a `<pre>` or have CSS rule `white-space: pre;` applied:

```
<pre>{{retreivedJson.attributeContainingWhitespaces}}</pre>

<!-- or -->

<div style="white-space: pre">{{retreivedJson.attributeContainingWhitespaces}}</div>
```

Here a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weycxj) showcasing all examples.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is what's being rendered.  If you want an HTML line break, you need to use an HTML tag, i.e., `<br>`.

If you're using a framework (e.g., Angular or Ionic), you might need to ensure your HTML tags aren't being escaped.